# Linux vs W11 String handling (keyboard/file) fgets/scanf

Tags: c, windows, unix, gcc, mingw

TERMINAL INPUT

```
char Buffer[50];

printf("Give a word to search: ");

fgets(lineBuffer, 50, stdin);
Buffer[strlen(Buffer)-1] = '\0';

//scanf("%s", Buffer);    <----- i also tried this 
//scanf("%*[^\n]");

fflush(stdin);


hash = HASH(Buffer, DICTIONARYSIZE);
```

FILE INPUT

```
char Buffer[50];
unsigned int key;

while (fgets(Buffer, 50, fp) != NULL)  //Loop until end of file
{
    Buffer[strlen(Buffer)-1] = '\0';
    key = HASH(Buffer, DICTIONARYSIZE);
```

In W11 with MinGW works fine no problems BUT in any Linux OS i tried it doesn't work the has is not the same.

I tried to remove any `\n` i cleaned the buffer but the same the hashes don't match and also if I use `strcmp` they are not the same. I don't know what the problem is any more maybe the Compiler.

Comment: If the file portion is not relevant to your question, it would be better to remove it. For the portion that is relevant, what does HASH do? What is some example input and what output did you expect? In other words, please provide a [mre].

Comment: And you might want to state *what* doesn't work.  What is the input, what was the output, what is the expected output.

Comment: unsigned int HASH(char* str, int DICTIONARYSIZE)
{
    unsigned int hash = 0;
    while (*str)
    {
        hash = *str + 31 * hash;
        str++;
    }
    return hash%DICTIONARYSIZE; 
}

Comment: ex. in my file i have the word ''scum'' and i get the hash 3 but in the terminal if i type the same ''scum'' i get hash 0 also i remove the \n with \0 and also in windows the hash's always are the same only in linux i get this.

Comment: My guess is there are invisible characters in the file, like a BOM character. If you print `strlen(Buffer)` is it the same?

Comment: yes the str in the file is 4 but at the terminal is 5 , do you know any eazy to remove it? do i also make in '/0'? but why windows allows this shit and Linux doesn't like wtf?

Comment: See [Using `fflush(stdin)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979209/15168) for a discussion (or several) on the (in)advisability of using `fflush(stdin)`.

Comment: Do you open the file in text mode or binary mode?  Are the CRLF line endings in the file screwing things up?  Have you done a byte-by-byte dump of the data you are hashing in the two programs?

Comment: i just do  this :   FILE *fp = fopen("d.txt", "r");

Comment: This is why an [MCVE] is so desirable; we wouldn't need to ask questions like this.  What you do should open a text file which should map CRLF line endings on disk to NL (LF) endings on input, and it should map NL (LF) line endings to CRLF if writing.  Have you dumped the data that you're getting as a series of hex bytes?  Is the input the same for both terminal and file input?  Note that many programs are written so that they read standard input (terminal or pipe) or from named files — so only one executable is needed for either sort of input.

Comment: int last = strlen(Buffer) - 1; while (last >= 0 && (Buffer[last] == '\n' || Buffer[last] == '\r')) { Buffer[last--] = '\0'; }

Comment: Doing `Buffer[strlen(Buffer)-1] = '\0';` is unnecessary (and does nothing). strlen(Buffer) looks for a null terminator so if its not present, this line is not going to add it. fgets does add a null terminator so you don't need it. I believe the issue is in Windows you have an extra carriage return byte which is not present in Linux. In windows you want to search for two chars '\r', '\n' and remove them while in Linux you want to just remove '\n'